# What does "Why is this the case" mean

Tags: meaning

So I got some questions for my paper, and this is one of them:

***"The development of Confucianism under Emperor Wudi of the Han dynasty was a great success. Why was this the case?"***

I don't understand the meaning of "why was this the case", is it asking me to analyse the reasons of the success of Confucianism or something else?

Comment: Yes. [Case](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/case#case_Noun_100): "an instance of a given situation". The given situation is the successful development of Confucianism. Why did that situation arise?

Comment: "Why was this true?"

Comment: "Is it asking me to analyse the reasons of the success of Confucianism?"  It's probably enough to list them.  Unless a careful reading of the assignment leads you to think you need to analyze them too.

Answer (score 2):

It means you have to describe why, *The development of Confucianism under Emperor Wudi of the Han dynasty was a great success*?

The above topic of Confucianism succeeding in development under this particular emperor seems to be a case. There were certain characteristics of the emperor or his administration that lead to the success of Confucianism during that time.

You have to list those characteristics.